# How to deploy Azure api app to marketplace

Tags: azure-api-apps

I have created an Azure API App and published it to my Azure account using Visual Studio. Used that as a connector in logic app and tested, its working fine.

Now I want to publish my app to Azure marketplace, how can i do that? Is there any guideline available that i can use to publish my API App to azure marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently not taking API app submissions in the Azure Marketplace. We will let you know when there is an updated partner program for integrating APIs with Logic Apps.

As an alternative, you can direct your customers to the HTTP connector in Logic Apps: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-connector-http/.  This built-in connector in Logic Apps allows customers to invoke any REST API.  In the coming months, we will improve this further, making it easier for customers to invoke these APIs when metadata is available.